# Identifying a connection with HTTPS in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, nginx

I'm expecting a connection to come via HTTPS to a rails app using a certificate self-signed with previously agreed certificate authority.

The spec for the API says that the user should be identified by their certificate. How would I go about identifying this user based on their ssl certificate?

I assume nginx will handle the connection - I can't seem to find any mention in any rails documentation that I'll know anything more about the ssl status apart from [request#ssl?](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Request/ssl%3F)

Comment: "*a certificate self-signed with previously agreed certificate authority*". This seems to contradict itself: either it's self-signed, or it's signed by a previously agreed CA (you wouldn't use the Root CA cert directly).

Comment: @bruno - Yes, sorry that was unclear. What I mean to say is - I've been provided with a certificate and the authority for that certificate - which is not a general Verisign (or co) one.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're planning to use SSL client certificates. You should be able to do this all in nginx using the `ssl_verify_client` config.

Here's a blog post that walks through the whole thing: http://rynop.wordpress.com/2012/11/26/howto-client-side-certificate-auth-with-nginx/

That will setup nginx to handle **authentication** for your application. If you need to do additional **authorization** (like check the user's role), you'll need to configure nginx to pass some user identity information to your application. Add something like this to your nginx config:

```
proxy_set_header USER_DN $ssl_client_s_dn;
```

then in your app, use something like this to access the DN from the certificate and look it up in your user store:

```
user_dn = request.headers["HTTP_USER_DN"]
user = User.where(dn: user_dn).first
```

Comment: Ideally the identification would be database driven, which I don't assume is doable in nginx?

Comment: I added an example of how you should be able to do that.